# Databind comobox in data-template with enum

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a list item data template that contains a textbox and a combobox.

I've two way databound the textbox to a public string property in the list item, but I want to be able to bind the combobox to an enum and display their public friendly versions in the combobox items and maintain the two way binding ability.

I'm still pretty new to the whole concept of databinding, and components of MVVM, but i'm picking it up fairly quickly. I've had a look around for similar requests however haven't been able to find suitable answers or anything I can understand / manipulate to work correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [blog post](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2011/12/27/Databinding-to-an-enumeration-in-WinRT.aspx) should help you out! Effectively you need a enum converter.

To convert an enum to a list use the following code:-

```
var colors = typeof(Colors).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties;
foreach (var item in colors)
{
   cbBorderColor.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: I've had a read of that, but i'm not sure how to wrangle it into a combobox, not just a selection of hard coded radio buttons.

Comment: To clarify my comment, I need to be able to tell the data template in xaml to use the enum as the item source.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, but I think my problem is somewhat unique or i've failed to explain it properly. However you are essentially correct.